# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while downloading image using universalimageloader

Tags: android, gridview, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I have custom adapter for GridView in which i am displaying data from server,
i am successful to display data but while i am scrolling gridview multiple time its gives me the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError my logcat error is as below :

for displaying image i am using universal image loader

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);  


DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_stub)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_stub)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
    .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .considerExifParams(false)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
    .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())


    .handler(new Handler())
    .build();  

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(image_url_string,
            image_coupon, options);

06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387): Process: com.example.coupon, PID: 4387
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at com.example.coupon.adapter.CouponsAdapter.getView(CouponsAdapter.java:113)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.GridView.correctTooLow(GridView.java:667)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:263)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4247)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-23 09:09:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me to solve this error. Thank You.

Comment: I am seeing OOM in UIL for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Here i suggest you just remove old instance before creating newinstance becase every time you create newinstance and previous memory doesnot release by old instance so when your device memory goes low after some attempts. it gives you outof Memory error. so just clear previous instance and memory.

Comment: Will you please explain me, are you talking about instance of ImageLoader ? if Yes then how can i remove old instance?

Comment: create one method in ImageLoader class then there are object allready available which is return in getInstance() method assign it to null. and call GC Method meand garbage collector method.and call it when you want.thats it

Answer (score 0):

Your need to remove old instance before creating new instance.